# looping over feature classes

Tags: arcpy, cursor, arcgis-10.5

I have the following script which selects the row with the maximum value in a specified field, and then deletes that record. This works when specifying a single input fc. I am working with ArcGIS 10.5.

```
fc = # the input feature class  
field = # the field in the fc to sort by  

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc, '', '', '', field + ' D') # sort "field" descending  

for row in rows: # read the rows  
    max = row.getValue(field) # get value in field  
    expr = '"' + field + '" = ' + str(max) # make "Where" expression  
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc, "NEW_SELECTION", expr) # make selection  
    arcpy.DeleteRows_management(fc)
    break # exit loop after first time
```

What I am trying to do, is loop this workflow over a list of feature classes (using ListFeatureClasses). I tried the following solution, which ran but didn't appear to do anything. (I'm running in the Python window at the moment, but would like it to run as a standalone script eventually).

```
>>> def deleterows(fc):
...     rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc, '', '', '', field + ' D') # sort "field" descending  
...   
... for row in rows: # read the rows  
...     max = row.getValue(field) # get value in field  
...     expr = '"' + field + '" = ' + str(max) # make "Where" expression  
...     arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc, "NEW_SELECTION", expr) # make selection  
...     arcpy.DeleteRows_management(fc)
...     break # exit loop after first time
...     
>>> for fc in fc_list:
...     deleterows(fc)

fc_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() # this is already defined before the above code runs.
```

I'm sure the answer is quite simple, but I'm still getting to grips with Python loops.

Comment: I would recommend only using new style (arcpy.da) cursors.

Comment: 1) While old-style cursors aren't deprecated,  you certainly shouldn't be learning to use them: use Data Access  (`da`) cursors instead. 2) Learn how to write scripts in a .py file: they are much easier to reproduce and debug 3) fix your indent scheme -- the rows `for`  loop is not within the function.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is with indention. The below lines need a further indentation:

```
... for row in rows: # read the rows  
...     max = row.getValue(field) # get value in field  
...     expr = '"' + field + '" = ' + str(max) # make "Where" expression  
...     arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc, "NEW_SELECTION", expr) # make selection  
...     arcpy.DeleteRows_management(fc)
...     break # exit loop after first time
```

To improve your code, a data access [UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) would be a more efficient solution.

```
def deleterows (fc, field):
    sqlClause = "ORDER BY {} DESC".format (field)
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (fc, "*", sql_clause = (None, sqlClause)) as curs:
        curs.next ()
        curs.deleteRow ()
```